# Why do we use a Handler? Why we don't call an interface element inside a Runnable object?

Tags: android, android-handler

Whenever this code is executed the application crashes, but when a handler is used the application works as expected.

```
 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long futuretime = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000;

            while(System.currentTimeMillis()<futuretime){
                synchronized (this){

                    try {
                        wait(futuretime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }
   //this code needs to be inside a Handler ??
           TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timedisplay);
        time.setText("Changed Man!!");
   //this code needs to be inside a Handler ??
        }

    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here all the answer have mentioned use of handler is used in Android with UI thread. But Let me add more to it.
If you have gone **Android documentation/tutorial** you would know that

> When an application component starts and the application does not have
>   any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux
>   process for the application with a single thread of execution. By
>   default, all components of the same application run in the same
>   process and thread (called the "main" thread or uiThread).

**for more info** [refer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Now coming to your mentioned example; **you have created another thread using Runnable...so there might be scenario you need thread(s) other then just mainThread in Android Application**.
If you are good in **JAVA Threading concept** then you would know how **Interthread communication happens and for different ways how it can be done [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831781/how-threads-communicate-with-each-other)**


So coming back to question **in android we have mainThread** or uiThread so called **which holds our ui** i.e. view component. **These component are private to mainThread so other thread cannot access it**...which has been mentioned in previous answer.
 This is where **Handler comes into picture** you do **not need to worry how your message would be passed from one thread to another**.
**Handler**

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
>   runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to
>   enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your
>   own.
> When posting or sending to a Handler, you can either allow the
>   item to be processed as soon as the message queue is ready to do so,
>   or specify a delay before it gets processed or absolute time for it to
>   be processed. The latter two allow you to implement timeouts, ticks,
>   and other timing-based behavior.

For more info refer [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) AND
For more info with [handler and UI thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html#Handler)

Answer (score 0):

Code that deals with the UI should be run on the UI (main) thread.

You (probably) create a handler on the UI thread, so all messages sent via it will run on that thread too.

Comment: **should** is a good word here since you can access UI components from any thread (ok from a thread that created them), see: http://pastebin.com/TESWTrf4

Comment: Handler runs inside run() method(in Runnable object),so why do we need to use the Handler and not write the code directly in the run() method

Answer (score 0):

The Runnable is use for background process(background thread) and textview is in your UI thread so background thread can't communicate with foreground thread so it will gives you error and crashes your application.you can also use the runOnUiThread. example.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            long futuretime = System.currentTimeMillis()+10000;

            while(System.currentTimeMillis()<futuretime){
                synchronized (this){

                    try {
                        wait(futuretime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            }

try {
                     // code runs in a thread
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
           TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timedisplay);
        time.setText("Changed Man!!");
                            }
                     });
               } catch (final Exception ex) {
                   Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
               }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
```

Comment: Handler is used to handle message which is passed by the thread to Main UI, so why does the thread use the handler to pass a message?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your app crashes is that you modify View from a non-UI thread.
If you do it using a Handler **that belongs to UI-thread** this works as expected.

**Update**
If you need to run Runnable to modify UI you may choose from:
1) yourActivity.[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))(Runnable r)
2) yourHandlerOnUIThread.[post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))(Runnable r)
3) yourView.[post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable))(Runnable r)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but why do we need  to use a handler?